# Animate image opacity from 0 to 100 and back to 0

Tags: jquery

I have one image which is stacked on top of another one. I am trying to animate the top image opacity to 0 and then back to 100 and then again to 0. This should continue in a loop. Is there a way i can achieve it ?? Please help..

```
$('.bannerHover').animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a simple recursive function that calls jQuery's fade function, and when complete, call itself again using the callback supplied by the fade function. With jQuery 1.4.4's [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function, it can be done as simply as:

```
var b = $('#block');
function fade(){
    b.fadeToggle(1000, fade);
}
fade();
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/FnBgL/ for a simple example